# Does Windows sc order queries in any fashion?

Tags: windows, service, scripting, nsis

Services are being managed using an NSIS installer. On uninstallation those services are stopped using `net stop`, because it is synchronous, then flagged for deletion using `sc delete`, as they do not have to be deleted immediately/synchronously.

Now I am wondering about the installation process. The order of calls is such:

1. `net stop service1`
2. `net stop service2`
3. `sc config service1 depend=dependency1`
4. `sc config service2 depend=dependency2`
5. `sc start service1`
6. `sc start service2`

Is there an intrinsic order to queries passed to `sc`? Are they worked through in the order `sc` is called (I assume they are not)? Are they being delegated to the respective service and queued there (this is what I hope for), *e.g.* whether `service1` or `service2` is stopped and configured first is ambiguous, but the `sc config`, `sc start` order is not? Is the order entirely ambiguous?

In addition I am curious to know what happens when mixing `net` and `sc` calls. Assume the following order:

1. `net stop service`
2. `sc config service`
3. `net start service`

Is it reasonable to assume that the service would likely be stopped, then started before any configuration occurred?

Supposedly the general question is, how to ensure proper service setup via concatenated `sc`/`net` calls. The required order:

1. Stop service (it may or may not exist on system)
2. Create service / conffigure service
3. Start service

Uninstallation is less pressing, because stopping services and flagging them for deletion is sufficient.

Comment: The NSIS wiki also has service plug-ins and macros you can use instead of calling sc.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing `sc` and `net` calls should not be a problem because it is the SCM (Service Control Manager) process that controls the services, other applications simply asks the SCM to perform a specific operation.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-changeserviceconfiga) for the `ChangeServiceConfig` API function states that:

> If the configuration is changed for a service that is running, with the exception of lpDisplayName, the changes do not take effect until the service is stopped.

This leads me to believe that a installer can use the following sequence:

Install/Configure --> Stop (synchronous) --> Start.

Performing "Stop --> Configure --> Start" is always going to have a race condition issue because another process might trigger a service start at the wrong time.

Comment: I guess all depends on whether or not SCM processes multiple queries at once. If the order of processing arrivingg queries is kept by the SCM, then stop->config->start and config->start->stop yield the same result. Otherwise, if there is no such guarantee, then neither stop->config->start, not config->stop->start seem to ensure that the service launches with an updated config. Hm.

Comment: Still, I want to upvote you, because this gives me some insights.

Comment: As a small update, I ran various orderings of `net start`, `net stop` and `sc config` via script, interestingly the order was kept so far everytime.

Comment: Start and stop are not instant operations, internally there are extra states like starting and stopping. It is possible for "stop, config, start" to become "stop, start(by a unrelated 3rd-party), config, start" and then the new config is not respected.

Comment: In my case there is no third party, however I agree, config, stop start is clearly the safer variant. Thanks!